# How to zoom and swipe multiple images coming from webservise in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, pinchzoom

1) In my application, I want to zoom and pinch an image. In xib file, there is a  imageView inside a scrollview.Page control is used for swiping images. For a single image it gets zoomed, but for multiple images(coming from web service) it is not getting swipe and zoom.
    In setMultipleImages method, images are not getting zoomed and swiped, while if image is single it gets zoom properly.
  2)  In `UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]]];` line code, want to replace uiimage with uiimageview. How can I do it?

My code is:

```
-(void)setMultipleImages{

    for (int i = 0; i <  [imageMArray count]; i++){
        NSString *logoName;

        NSArray *imageNameArray = [[imageMArray objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];

        logoName = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[imageNameArray lastObject]];

        if (![[AppDelegateHelper getInstance] fileExist:logoName])
        {
            NSString *imageURL = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@%@",[UrlBuilder getWebsiteUrl],[imageMArray objectAtIndex:i]];

            [self startProcessing];

           UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]]];

            [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
           DebugLog(@"%f,%f",image.size.width,image.size.height);

            NSArray *docDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *cacheDirectory = [docDir objectAtIndex:0];
            DebugLog(@"saving png");

            NSString *pngFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",cacheDirectory,[imageNameArray lastObject]];

          NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f)];

          [data1 writeToFile:pngFilePath atomically:YES];
        }
    }

    [self loadImageData];
}

 -(void)loadImageData
{
    int X =0;
    for (int s=0; s<imageMArray.count; s++) {
        NSString *logoName;

        NSArray *imageNameArray = [[imageMArray objectAtIndex:s] componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];


        logoName = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[imageNameArray lastObject]];


        if([[AppDelegateHelper getInstance] loadImage:logoName] != nil)
        {
          //  UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(X, 0, scrollView.frame.size.width, 300)] ;

            [imageView setImage:[[AppDelegateHelper getInstance] loadImage:logoName]];

            imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

            [scrollView addSubview: imageView];

            X = X + imageView.frame.size.width;
        }
        else
        {
            //UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(X, 0, scrollView.frame.size.width, 300)] ;

            [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NoImage.png"]];

            imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

            [scrollView addSubview: imageView];

            X = X + imageView.frame.size.width;
        }
    }

    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = [imageMArray count];

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(X,scrollView.frame.size.height);

    lblCount.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"1 sur %lu",(unsigned long)imageMArray.count];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add all your images to imageview. Then apply pinchguesture to images view for zoom effect.

Pinch Guesture:

```
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *imageviewguesture=[[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(ImageViewPinchGuesture:)];
```

add pinch guesture to your image view:

```
[YourImageView addGestureRecognizer:imageviewguesture];
```

Make your selector method:

```
-(void)ImageViewPinchGuesture:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinGuestureregonizer{    
pinGuestureregonizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(pinGuestureregonizer.view.transform, pinGuestureregonizer.scale, pinGuestureregonizer.scale);
pinGuestureregonizer.scale = 1;
}
```

In your .h file add this line

```
-(void)ImageViewPinchGuesture:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinGuestureregonizer;
```

To check effect in simulator Press Cmd+alt then press left mouse pad button and drag.

Hope this will Help. Don't forget to accept the answer if it helps you.